# Maximal Ideals of $R_f$ can be identied with those maximal ideals of R which don’t contain f

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Assume $R$ to be finitely generated over an algebraically closed field.

I proved that prime ideals of $R_f$ can be identified with those prime ideals of $R$ not containing f. But I don’t know how to proceed for maximal ideal.

Any hlo isn’t appreciated!!

Comment: What is $R_f$?  Help me out here!

Comment: When you proved it for prime ideals, did you notice what the correspondence looks like when you consider an inclusion of ideals?